# How to compare the list items in a flat list in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Good day, I have a flat list that renders some events, that have a startDate property, which functions as the title of the event. My question is, how can I compare the items in the renderItem function so that if two events have the same startDate I show it only once.

```
const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Text style={[sharedStyles.bigTextBold, { marginVertical: 20 }]}>{moment(item.startDate).startOf('day').isSame(moment(item.startDate).startOf('day'))}</Text>
        <Event
          containerStyle={index !== 0 && { marginBottom: 10 }}
          key={item._id}
          data={item}
          onPress={() => {
            Nav.navigate('CommunityCalendarView', {
              data: item,
              communityId,
              propertyId
            })
          }}
        />
      </>
    )
  }

  <FlatList
            style={[styles.flatListContainer]}
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onEndReached={handleLoadMoreEvents}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 60 }}
            ListFooterComponent={() => {
              return (
                <>
                  {loading && <ActivityIndicator size='small' color={EStyleSheet.value('$green')} />}
                  {emptyState && !data.length &&
                    <Text
                      style={[sharedStyles.textLight,
                        { textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 20 }
                      ]}
                    >
                      {translate('community.calendar.noEventsSearchResultText')}
                    </Text>}
                </>
              )
            }}
          />}
```

In my code I pass the item and the index, but I don't really know how to compare the different items while they are being rendered

Comment: As a rule of thumb, keep as much logic out of UI component as possible. In your case, `FlatList` shall only do one thing: take whatever is in `data` and render it. As for which one to render and which one not, that decision should be made before `data` reach `FlatList`.

Comment: There is also another layer of nuance. When two events have the same `startDate`, which one do you choose to display? The first one or the second one? What if there are more than two events sharing the same `startDate`? I'd recommend you setting up a map, with the key being `startDate`, and value being the event to display. You can workout the logic of which event to choose when building the map. Then you can pass the map's values as `data` to `FlatList`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter your `data` to have a unique data set.

```
data = {data.filter((value, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.startDate == value.startDate
  ))
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do that before the FlatList consume the data.

```js
const data = [
  
{
  startDate: "fooDate",
user:"Foo"},

{startDate:"barDate",
user:"Bar"},

{startDate:"bazDate",
user:"Baz"},

{startDate:"barDate",
user:"Bar"}
]

const isSameStartDate = (value) => (el) => el.startDate === value.startDate

const newData = data.filter((value, index, array) => index === array.findIndex(isSameStartDate(value))
)
```

Then just:

```js
<FlatList data={newData} {…props} />
```